# ".jobs" accepted usage

Tags: domains

Wikipedia states "The intended use of the domain jobs is for companies and organizations to register some version of their corporate names and use it for a site aimed at those seeking employment with that company, **or, .jobs can target a specific market. For example, manufacturing.jobs could represent employment for a specific corporation, or market sector.**"

The intention is the latter of these use cases, but other sources state only the former use case.

Does anyone have any experience and is able to clarify if in fact a ".jobs" told can be bought for targeting a niche?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consult what is at the registry website, this is the only authoritative source. Or consult a **knowledgeable** registrar about it.

If you go to https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/jobs.html you can find who is the registry, you have a link at the bottom. Then you arrive at the policies page at http://goto.jobs/policies/ that explains who can and can not register a `.jobs` domain name.

> .jobs applications must be submitted by you as set forth in Appendix A
>   – Applicant Qualifications. You represent and warrant that, upon
>   application for a .jobs domain and during the registration thereof,
>   you comply with the requirements set forth in Appendix A. .jobs
>   applications will only be accepted for .jobs domains which are
>   included in a product category set forth in Appendix B – Product
>   Categories. .jobs domains may only be used as set forth in Appendix C
>   – Sponsored TLD Compliance. You represent and warrant that during the
>   term of registration of your .jobs domain you will use the .jobs
>   domain in compliance with the provisions of Appendix C.

And then

> Appendix A – Applicant Qualifications
>
> The .jobs Top-Level Domain is a sponsored Top-Level Domain. All
>   applicants for .jobs domain names must comply with the terms set forth
>   in the .jobs Charter, including but not limited to Section IV:
>
> The following persons may request registration of a second-level
>   domain within the .JOBS TLD:
>   * members of SHRM; or
>   * persons engaged in human resource management practices that meet any of the following criteria: (i) possess salaried-level human resource
>   management experience; (ii) are certified by the Human Resource
>   Certification Institute; (iii) are supportive of the SHRM Code of
>   Ethical and Professional Standards in Human Resource Management, as
>   amended from time to time, a copy of which is attached hereto.

The end of Appendix B has the following that pertains to your question:

> Non-“companyname” category.
>
> Non-“companyname” names are domains that are not company names, such
>   as industry, occupation, geographic, dictionary terms and/or
>   combinations thereof. Any .jobs domain allocated under this category
>   is allocated under terms and conditions set forth by us in our sole
>   discretion.

If you go back to main page you find a link for that case:
http://goto.jobs/non-company-names-reg/

You have a form to fill, and then as written above: "Any .jobs domain allocated under this category is allocated ... in our sole discretion".

So your application may or may not work. You can ask the registry and again a knowledgeable registrar to help you in this endeavor and let you know the chances you have to secure the .JOBS domain you like.